# Image pushing content off page

Tags: html, css, image, height, responsive

Here is my site:  http://www.requitedesigns.com/seele/

To see the problem, you'd have to load up the site in Chrome or FF responsive mode, say the iPhone responsive mode.  Scroll to the bottom.  You should see the bottom of the page where the copyright is, is not quite there.  It's as if it hangs up somewhere around Featured Author or Featured Video.

The reason seems to be the coloumn image, in the middle of the page, the one next to "Ultimate Shortcodes".  If I hide that image by removing it's height (set by the matchHeight JS library), I can then see the content at the bottom of that page.  But, restore that image height, and the content gets pushed down off screen?  I must be missing something.  I can't figure out why that happens.  I tried disabling all the overflow CSS, to no avail.  Is there a CSS guru out there who can point me in the correct direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) working code snippet, link reference is of no use for future users if it suddenly disappears, a local snippet will always be available

Comment: I can't provide a snippet, it's an entire site with javascript and css.  I assure you tho, the sites not going anywhere for a long, long time.  Sorry.  Wish it was easy as jiddle.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: If you were to be Google and said it will stay, I still will say the same ... local snippet is here forever and that what matters

Comment: Not only that, but working on reducing your issue to a [mcve] often helps you come to the solution.

Comment: If you open your webpage in Chrome and go to Developer tools > Event Listeners > Scroll > Window > Click "Remove". After removing that listener, you would be able to scroll down. This is the problem are and I do not know the reason but you can move ahead from there. **Hack** : Insert `<div style="height:500px; background-color:#222222;"></div>` just before the ending `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I added a min-height css, seemed to fix it.  Not sure why.  Oh well.  Sorry I could not duplicate an ENTIRE SITE for most of you chaps.